# find why mdadm dropped a disk

Tags: raid, mdadm, software-raid

I have had mdadm drop a disk twice in the last month or two. I re-added it last time and it ran fine for a while, then I noticed it was running in degraded mode again. I wondered how I find the "reason" it dropped the drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the system logs: typically `/var/log/messages` and/or the output of the `journalctl -xe` command. If the drive failed recently, the kernel message buffer (viewable with the `dmesg` command) may also have messages about it.

Normally, the `dmesg` messages will also get stored into the logs, but the logging subsystem may have been configured to ignore some of the lower-priority kernel messages, so there might be more detail present in the `dmesg` output.

What you're likely to see is a burst of disk I/O error/timeout messages and somewhere among or after them a message from the RAID subsystem that it's marking the drive as failed. Basically, if the RAID subsystem detects that a disk starts reporting that it's failing I/O (read or write) requests, or timing out on them, for any reason, the disk will be marked as failed.

For more clues, you might also want to use `smartctl -a` on the dropped disk, to see what kind of results its own internal health checks are reporting.

Comment: So I got a new disk, added it to array, started rebuild and got more errors. Took me a few days to realize I had a bad SATA cable... Sometimes it's easy to forget to start "at the bottom".